# I can not separate a list to others on properties

Tags: c#, properties, generic-list

**When I try to separate Cards to other lists I get Stack Overflow Exception. How can I fix it? **

I don't know which way is best. Doing it at on properties or in a method.

```
public static List<Card>? cards
{
    get
    {
        return cards;
    }
    set
    {
        foreach (var linesorgu in value)
        {
            if (linesorgu.line == "3" || linesorgu.line.ToLower() == "done")
            {
                done.Add(linesorgu);
                cards.Remove(linesorgu);
            }
            else if (linesorgu.line == "2" || linesorgu.line.ToLower() == "inprog")
            {
                InProg.Add(linesorgu);
                cards.Remove(linesorgu);
            }
            else if (linesorgu.line == "1" || linesorgu.line.ToLower() == "todo")
            {
                todo.Add(linesorgu);
                cards.Remove(linesorgu);
            }
            else { Console.WriteLine("Line yazımında bir yanlış var"); }
              
              cards = value;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to introduce backing field. Currently in your getter and setter your are calling the `card` property itself which results in "infinite" recursion which ends up with SO exception. Also note that `cards.Remove(linesorgu);` will not actually work because at some point you will try to modify iterated collection.

```cs
private static List<Card> _cards;
public static List<Card>? cards
{
    get
    {
        return _cards;
    }
    set
    {
        var newCards = new List<Card>();
        foreach (var linesorgu in value)
        {
            if (linesorgu.line == "3" || linesorgu.line.ToLower() == "done")
            {
                done.Add(linesorgu);
            }
            else if (linesorgu.line == "2" || linesorgu.line.ToLower() == "inprog")
            {
                InProg.Add(linesorgu);
            }
            else if (linesorgu.line == "1" || linesorgu.line.ToLower() == "todo")
            {
                todo.Add(linesorgu);
            }
            else
            {
                newCards.Add(linesorgu);
                Console.WriteLine("Line yazımında bir yanlış var");
            }
        }

        _cards = newCards;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help. But now I got NullReferenceException when i create an object at another class. What should i do now?

Comment: @İnanAkalin you need to instantiate value for the field/property/variable.. in question.